# Get Velocity from Acceleration data(10 Hz), using "cumsum" or Omega Arithmetic Method

Tags: matlab, velocity, numerical-integration, cumsum, acceleration

I want to get Velocity from Acceleration data(10 Hz) in MATLAB. I have the real Constant Velocity that I've calculated by (DeltaX/DeltaT). The problem is that when I use the code below, the graph has lot's of differences with the Real Velocity Graph. I've used both cumsum and omega arithmetic, could someone tell me if there is any problem in my codes of any of both methods? Thank you in advance.
link to access txt files: https://spaces.hightail.com/space/19rl7

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% cumsum METHOD %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
fid1 = fopen( 'Acceleration_data.txt', 'r' );
fid2 = fopen( 'Actual_Velocity_data.txt', 'r' );
formatSpec = '%f';
vel_Fast_Running = fscanf(fid2,formatSpec);
acc_Fast_Running = fscanf(fid1,formatSpec);
Fs=1000;
Ns = 10;%% Sampling freq
T = 1/Fs; %% Period
L = length(acc_Fast_Running); %% signal length
acceleration_data=acc_Fast_Running-median(acc_Fast_Running);
[B,A] = butter(6,0.098,'high'); %% highpass filter
a_filtr = filtfilt(B,A,acc_Fast_Running); %% acceleratiof w/o DC
v_cumsum = cumsum(a_filtr)*0.1;%integration
v_cumsum = v_cumsum - mean(v_cumsum);
[B,A] = butter(3,0.12,'low'); 
v_cumsum_filtr = filtfilt(B,A,v_cumsum);
%subplot(1,2,2);plot([v_cumsum' v_cumsum_filtr']);
hold on;plot(vel_Fast_Running)
plot(v_cumsum_filtr)
legend('Actual Vel','Vel From integration')
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Velocity m/s')

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% OMEGA ARITHMETIC METHOD %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
fid1 = fopen( 'Acceleration_data.txt', 'r' );
fid2 = fopen( 'Actual_Velocity_data.txt', 'r' );
formatSpec = '%f';
vel_Fast_Running = fscanf(fid2,formatSpec);
acc_Fast_Running = fscanf(fid1,formatSpec);
Fs=1000;
Ns = 10;%% Sampling freq
T = 1/Fs; %% Period
L = length(acc_Fast_Running ); %% signal length
%t=(1:L)/Fs;
f = Fs*(0:L-1)/L;
acc_Fast_Running =acc_Fast_Running -mean(acc_Fast_Running );
[B,A] = butter(6,0.098,'high'); %% highpass filter
a_filtr = filtfilt(B,A,acc_Fast_Running);
Y = (fft(a_filtr)); % Fast fourier Transform
for i = 1 : L 
   if f(i) ~= 0 && f(i) < Fs/2;
       Yf(i) = Y(i)/(2*pi*f(i)*sqrt(-1)) ;
   else  
       Yf(i) = 0;
   end
end
Yf(1:100)=0; %% 
d_oa = real(ifft(Yf));
d1 = designfilt('lowpassiir','FilterOrder',4, ...
 'HalfPowerFrequency',0.1,'DesignMethod','butter');
y = filtfilt(d1,d_oa);
figure(15)
%plot( d_oa)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(y)
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Vel be Omega Method')
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(vel_Fast_Running )
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Actual Velocity m/s')
```

[image]

Comment: There is no data to run the code, no picture to judge based upon. However, in my experience, the calculated velocity through integration can be different that the actual velocity depending on initial conditions and velocity/acceleration profile.

Comment: Dear NKN, You are right. So I have edited my post and I've attached the picture and also data_files to run my codes

Comment: @NKN 
could you check it now?

Comment: Do we have to take care by applying g (9.81 m2 /sec)